# css print preview page is cut

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, print-preview

As you can see in this [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OrYsT.png), The title of the next table is being cut when the first table is having more records, sometimes the table before page break is long sometimes its short.

How can i make a dynamic margin adjustment at the bottom? To avoid those unwanted cutoffs?

```
    @page {
      margin-top: 13mm;
      margin-left: 1px;
      margin-right: 1px;
      size: short;
    }
    @media print {
      html, body {
        width: 250mm;
        height: 297mm;
      }
      /* ... the rest of the rules ... */
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

according to your images, I guess you can try `page-break-before` or `page-break-after`

```
@media print {
    h1 {
        page-break-before: auto | always | avoid | left | right | inherit;
        page-break-after:  auto | always | avoid | left | right | inherit;
    }
}
```

And two articles might explain these two CSS properties, [click here](https://tympanus.net/codrops/css_reference/page-break-after/) and [click here](https://tympanus.net/codrops/css_reference/page-break-before/)

if you can provide some code or example on [fiddler](https://jsfiddle.net/) will be awesome for others to help you